# Beamer navigation sidebar: change colors of name and title

Tags: beamer, sidebar

i set up a navigation bar to the right using: 
`\useoutertheme[right,width = 3cm]{sidebar}`

Now it looks like this:

First Question:

How can i change the color of the title "The Title"?

In the manual i only found the `setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{...}` but i couldn't find the name of the title. `title in sidebar` did not work.

Second Question:

Is it possible to change the alignment of the sections (testsection,hallo) to centered and leave out the subsection or to draw a vertical line on the left side of the sidebar?

EDIT: 
Minimum Working Example:

```
%%% For normal presentations
%\documentclass{beamer}
%%%

%%% For handouts with lots of extra notes
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
%\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\useoutertheme[right,width = 3cm]{sidebar}
\begin{document}
\section{testsection}
\begin{frame}
Here's some content, with no notes added.
\end{frame}
\section{hallo}
\begin{frame}
Here's some content, with notes added.
\end{frame}
\section{asdf}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: i edited the question. Could somebody unhold it??

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to add an example document that reproduces the issue, an MWE makes it much easier to investigate your issue and is often even necessary to make your question answerable in the first place. I'm sure the question will be reopened and answered in now time. For future questions you may want to keep in mind that it is generally preferred on this site to only as one question per question. So in future you may want to split questions like this with two problems into two separate questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. To change the colour of the title:

   ```
   \setbeamercolor{title in sidebar}{fg=red}
   ```
2. The option `hideallsubsections` will hide the subsections
3. To centre the content of the sidebar, you can add `center` to the sidebar format

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\useoutertheme[right,width = 3cm,hideallsubsections]{sidebar}

\setbeamercolor{title in sidebar}{fg=red}


\makeatletter
\def\beamer@sidebarformat#1#2#3{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\beamer@sidebarwidth,leftskip=#1,rightskip=1ex plus1fil,vmode,center]{#2}
    \vbox{}%
    #3\par%
    \vbox{}%
    \vskip-1.5ex%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{testsection}
\subsection{subsection name}
\begin{frame}
Here's some content, with no notes added.
\end{frame}

\section{hallo}
\begin{frame}
Here's some content, with notes added.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like it. Thank you. May i ask where you get that information from? 
I searched the whole `beameruserguide` but couldn't find `title in sidebar`. For example: Where would i search i also want to change the color of current section in the sidebar?

Comment: @musthave see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458193/36296 for a summary how to find out colour names